# How to disable vBulletin birthday emails?

Tags: email, forum, vbulletin

Another year, another inbox full of birthday messages from random vBulletin forums I signed up for once and have not visited in years:

> #### Happy Birthday from FORUM_NAME Forums
>
> Hello USER_NAME,
>
> We at FORUM_NAME Forums would like to wish you a happy birthday today!

As a vBulletin forum administrator:

- Can I include an **"Unsubscribe" link** or otherwise enable forum members to make individual choices about their birthday correspondence?
- How can I entirely stop sending birthday emails to all of my members?

Comment: The question about administering vBulletin is on-topic here, but the question about how users could adjust their settings would not be.  I edited it to remove the off-topic portion

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off birthday emails **globally** in AdminCP -> Scheduled Tasks Manager.  Search for "birthday" and disable the task.

You can also educate your members to turn off Admin emails or to remove their birthday from their profiles.